# How to set value in a cell based on another cell value from another column using formula or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have two sheets:[image]

**Sheet 1 :** consist of three columns (**Status**, **Cost**, **Version**)

**Sheet 2 :** Used as an Action Page with two columns (**Formula**, **Version Number**).

**Question:**

I want to set a version number in column two in sheet 2 and let the formula or the Button using VBA code to do the following:

1. The User set **value =** 5 in column 2 [Version Number] sheet 2
2. The System takes the value from **[Version Number] cell**
3. The System search for all rows containing the **[Version Number] value = 5** ,  in sheet 1 column [Version]
4. The System Replace each cell in column [**Status**] having [**Version**] value= 5 , with **Status Value =** "Delivered".

Any help please either throw formula or using the VBA Code.

Regards

Comment: You will need VBA to achieve this. But please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank you all for your advice , after searching for the key code to know how to return the number of rows filled in a specific table , I found the solution and now I am able to do my logic. Below is my solution for the above question.

**Steps:**

1. Create Variable to hold the values
2. The below variable will hold the inserted value need to be updated
3. The below variable will hold the Item Version  Column number in the table
4. The below variable will hold the value of each row under the column [Get_Version_Item_Column] to be used when comparing the values of each row
5. The below variable will hold the Item Progress Column number in the table
6. The below variable will hold the value of each row under the column [Get_Item_Progress_Column] to be used when comparing the values or each row
7. The below variable used to get the total number of used rows in the table
8. The below variable used as a counter to go throw a loop for all the rows

**Create a Function that will do the below in Order:**

9. Get Column Number from table 1 Sheet1 where header name = [Fixed in Version]
10. Get Column Number from table 1 Sheet1 where header name = [Item Progress]
11. Select Sheet 2 to get the value inserted in the Cell B1
12. Get Inserted value from the cell located inside the Sheet2
13. Set Counter value = 1 to start the loop from the first row after the header in table 1 Sheet 1
14. Open while Loop and set a condition if counter <= Total number of rows do the below
15. Start moving row by row in the table using the Cells Method : Cells(counter, Get_Version_Item_Column) ' in the cells method we set the [Row]=> counter variable which starts with value = 1 , [Column]=> Get_Version_Item_Column '
16. Get the value of the second column we want to put into the condition with the same way shown in Step 7
17. Start setting the condition usinf IF Else
18. If Get_Fixed_In_Version_Value = Get_Version_Inserted_Value And Get_Item_Progress_Value = "Approved" Then 'IF CORRECT NUMBER ' DO something Example [Replace the value in this row , this column , this cell with value = "" ]
19. Else ' Do something Else
20. Add 1 to the counter
21. Close the While Loop

**Code Solution:**

```
Public Get_Version_Inserted_Value As String
Public Get_Version_Item_Column As Integer
Public Get_Fixed_In_Version_Value As String
Public Get_Item_Progress_Column As Integer
Public Get_Item_Progress_Value As String
Public QATotal_Items_Row As Integer
Public counter As Integer

Function Change_Version_Item_Progress() As String

Get_Version_Inserted_Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value2

Get_Version_Item_Column = Application.Match("Fixed in Version", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)

Get_Item_Progress_Column = Application.Match("Item Progress", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)

Sheets(Sheet1).Select
QATotal_Items_Row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) - 1 
counter = 1
 While counter <= QATotal_Items_Row

    Get_Fixed_In_Version_Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").Cells(counter, Get_Version_Item_Column).Value2

    Get_Item_Progress_Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").Cells(counter, Get_Item_Progress_Column).Value2

    If Get_Fixed_In_Version_Value = Get_Version_Inserted_Value And Get_Item_Progress_Value = "Approved" Then 

        Get_Item_Progress_Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").Cells(counter, Get_Item_Progress_Column).Value = "Delivered"

    Else 
        Get_Item_Progress_Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").Cells(counter, Get_Item_Progress_Column).Value = Get_Item_Progress_Value

    End If
        counter = counter + 1 
    Wend

End Function
```

Hope it will help.

Regards

Comment: Thank you Patrick for the format , I always face problem in customizing the code into this format . lol hhh

Answer (score 2):

If that's all you want to achieve, and if you can use a formula in **Sheet1**, in the **[Status]** field, then probably all you want to do is to use the following formula:

```
=IF(C2 = 5, "Delivered", "Pending")
```

This is basically looking at your **Version** column and checks if your version number is **5**, then change the text to **Delivered**, else use **Pending** (or whatever you need).

Comment: Thank you DarXyde, for your help.while the solution you provided is to set a Formula inside the cell itself. But my question is different where each cell has a drop-down List so I don`t need to set a formula inside, I will attache an image for your reference it will describe my question more.

Comment: Is a bit more clear now, and yes, you will need some VBA to help you with that. As @Pᴇʜ pointed out, unfortunately this requires a bit of work from your side too.

All I can say, is very likely sheet events will help, and this might give you a starter on how to use those: https://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba/worksheet_events.php

Comment: I suggest to use a button instead of events. This is what users are familiar with and it's easier to achieve.